# Why doesn't express redirect properly when I edit the status code

Tags: node.js, http, express

The standard `res.redirect('/some/path');` behaves as expected and immediately redirects the request to `/some/path`, but if I add a status code, e.g., `res.redirect(401, '/some/path')` and I navigate to the redirecting page, `express` doesn't redirect to `/some/path`, instead I just get the following page:

```
<p>Unauthorized. Redirecting to <a href="/some/path">/</a></p>
```

and it never redirects. This is the same for any status code I supply just by the way.

Why doesn't a code specified redirect work as I'm expecting it to and how can I return a custom status code and redirect to a different path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior of the `Location` header, which is used to to redirect someone, is only defined for status codes in the 3xx range, and for 201/202 statuses. Since you are setting the status code to 401, it is ignoring the header and just rendering the response content. It just happens that Express includes some nice text explaining that the user is being redirected in case the redirect is slow.

Also, given the definition of the `401` status code, you are likely misusing it. The `401` code is to let the client know that it needs to send additional authentication information with a give request, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication, so you should not be redirecting to another URL.

Comment: I'd like to send the code '401' and tell the client to redirect the user to the login page. How would I do that in one step with Angular (without misusing the 401)? Currently my work around is to use a 302.

Comment: `401` response codes are for use with HTTP basic auth, which shows a popup box in the browser, so it has no login form other than the browser. If you are implementing your own login form, you should not be using `401`. Note the description in [the HTTP/1.1 code specs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2) `The response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field (section 14.47) containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource.`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I'm not sure what to do in the following case. I have a JWT token in a http only cookie.  Let's say a user is not logged in, and is trying to access `/account`. In this case in my code I check if there is a JWT token on `req.cookies`, and if there is no token I just `res.redirect('/log-in')`. It works, however I don't think it's correct because the status code should be 401 under normal circumstances. My question is what to do in this case? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I'd expect 401 to be the status code if you are sending a JWT to an API, but if you're redirecting then that doesn't seem to be the case so the redirect is the important state you are returning instead this a 3xx code makes more sense. Please ask an official SO question if you have more thoughts though, comments aren't the right place for this discussion.