# express js redirect with angular js

Tags: angularjs, http, redirect, express

I do http.get from angular js

```
$http.get('/api/users?id='+userID)
```

Further if unauthorized I do redirect with status from express js

```
res.status(401).location('/login').end();
```

Вut a response from the server 200 with login page in a response data

Why return status is 200 and not 401 how to fix it?

and my [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309821/express-js-redirect)

Comment: You must redirect user in client side: windows.location.href='/login'

Comment: @MBN I see that I have received the data and redirect? Why can not get the status of 401?

Comment: 123 I made as it is written [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29482118/5507287)

Answer (score 0):

You must redirect user in client side. Try this:

```
$http.get('/api/users?id='+userID).error(function(data, status){

    if(status==401){
        window.location.href='/login';
    }

});
```

Server side:

```
res.status(401).send({ hasError: true });
```

Comment: You have a rest api and you can't redirect directly on server side

Answer (score 0):

Your `$http.get` is waiting for a response which in your case is just the login page, and not a redirect instruction. Therefore you need to respond with a status code, then redirect on the client side.

```
$http.get('/api/users?id='+userID).error(function(data, status){

    if(status==401){
        $window.location.href='/login';
    }

});
```

On the server side, if they're not authorized, just send a status code.

```
res.status(401).end();
```